# Terraform version 1.1.9 doesn't support list function

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am in process to upgrade terraform version 1.1.9 for our application modules and but getting an below in .tf file.

```
Error:
│ Call to function "list" failed: the "list" function was deprecated in
│ Terraform v0.12 and is no longer available; use tolist([ ... ]) syntax to
│ write a literal list.
```

code snippet:

```
ec2MidSubnetIds = coalesce(var.ec2MidSubnetIds, lookup(local.solution_data["config"], "ec2MidSubnetIds", list(local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_a_index]["id"], local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_b_index]["id"], local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_c_index]["id"])))
```

Can someone please help me to modify the code with "tolist" function or any other way to get it sorted ?
because i have tried this with "tolist" as well but got an different error as you can see below,

```
Error: 
Invalid function argument
ec2ConfSubnets= coalesce(var.ec2ConfSubnets, lookup(local.solution_data["config"], "ec2ConfSubnets", tolist(local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_a_index]["id"]), tolist(local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_b_index]["id"]), tolist(local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_c_index]["id"])))

Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert string to list of any single
type.

Error: Invalid function argument
```

Comment: Have you actually tried using `tolist` only once, i.e., `tolist(local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_a_index]["id"], local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_b_index]["id"], local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_c_index]["id"])`?

Comment: Yes, i tried the same but getting below error:
 ec2ConfSubnetIds    = coalesce(var.ec2ConfSubnetIds, lookup(local.solution_data["config"], "ec2ConfSubnetIds", tolist(local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_a_index]["cidr_block"], local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_b_index]["cidr_block"], local.subnets[local.mid_subnets_c_index]["cidr_block"])))


Function "tolist" expects only 1 argument(s).

Comment: Seeing the same issue here